# Angular Unit Testing: Isolate certain components defined on module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angularjs-controller

I've inherited a large AngularJS project using Karma and Jasmine and am trying to follow the conventions that were set out before me, but am having trouble unit testing directive/controller modules.  Each module is defined like this:

```
angular
  .module('ap.panels.ContinuousDeliverySearchPanel', [])
  .directive('continuousDeliverySearchPanel', ContinuousDeliverySearchPanel)
  .controller('continuousDeliverySearchPanelCtrl', ContinuousDeliverySearchPanelCtrl);

function ContinuousDeliverySearchPanel() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/panels/continuous-delivery-search-panel/continuous-delivery-search-panel.html',
    controller: 'continuousDeliverySearchPanelCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
      search: '='
    }
  };
}
```

Where there is both a directive and controller defined on the module and the controller is bound to the directive.  I would like to create two sets of tests, one for the controller and one for the directive.  The issue that I run into is when testing the directive, I simply want to test if the element has been compiled correctly, but am forced to deal with the controller's http calls and dependencies.  Here is an example of my Directive test:

```
describe('ap.panels.ContinuousDeliverySearchPanel', function () {

  var scope, template, element;

  beforeEach(module('ap.panels.ContinuousDeliverySearchPanel'));

  beforeEach(inject( function ($rootScope, $compile){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    template = angular.element('<continuous-delivery-search-panel></continuous-delivery-search-panel>');
    element = $compile(template, scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('Should: compile search panel directive', function() {
    expect(element).toBeDefined();
  });

});
```

When the $compile is called, the continuousDeliverySearchPanelCtrl runs and starts throwing errors because it has a bunch of dependencies and http requests that aren't being mocked or dealt with.  However, I have no desire to mock any of this out because I'm not even testing the controller.  I'd like to do that separately in another file where I isolate the controller for testing.

Is there a way to pass in an empty controller or isolate just the directive in order to successfully test if it compiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you'll just have to mock the controller.

Try something like this:

```
module('foobar', function($provide, $controllerProvider) {
        $controllerProvider.register('FooBarController', function($scope) {
            // Controller Mock                
        });

    });
```

[documentation for controllerProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider)

[documentation for $provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide)